# Reading in ascii data lines with missing cells?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, ascii

I have an ascii file that has 3 lines of data that looks like this:

```
Timestamp: 00:47:14 SATID 13 VAL1 28 VAL2 227 SIGNAL 37                                     SATID 15 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL 30 SATID 16 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL 30
Timestamp: 00:48:14 SATID 13 VAL1 28 VAL2 227 SIGNAL 37                                     SATID 15 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL nan SATID 16 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL 30
Timestamp: 00:49:14                                     SATID 14 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL 30
```

(Please see image for original formatting). [original ascii data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdoEn.png) When I try to read it into Python, though, I get the following error:

```
time,sat1,sat2,sat3,sat4 = np.loadtxt("test1.asc", usecols=(1,9,17,25,33), unpack=True, converters = {1: strpdate2num("%H:%M:%S")})
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 839, in loadtxt
vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone know how I can do so that Python ignores the empty cells and read whatever data is available in each column?

Thanks!

Comment: The columns in you file have fixed widths. You probably should use `pd.read_fwf()` from Pandas.

Comment: Hi DYZ. Unfortunately the columns sometimes have slightly different widths...

Comment: Do values in neighboring columns ever overlap? If not (as in your example), you can still treat them as fixed-width.

Comment: DYZ, thanks for the tip re. the use of pd.read_fwf()  By any chance do you have an example of how I could use this module? Thanks! Btw, none of the columns overlap, so I think it would be possible to use the method you suggest...

Answer (score 0):

without grabbing `numpy` or `pandas`, lets see how we would read this "*manually*"

First recognise that the timestamp is always in the same place, following with `" SATID "`, so you can do a `.split(' SATID ')[0]` to get that info.

Then it seems if you do a `.split(' SATID ')` on the remainder of the info, you get all required info, which then you can split further.

in code this would look something like this:

```
raw_data = ["Timestamp: 00:47:14 SATID 13 VAL1 28 VAL2 227 SIGNAL 37                                     SATID 15 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL 30 SATID 16 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL 30",
            "Timestamp: 00:48:14 SATID 13 VAL1 28 VAL2 227 SIGNAL 37                                     SATID 15 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL nan SATID 16 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL 30",
            "Timestamp: 00:49:14                                     SATID 14 VAL1 22 VAL2 265 SIGNAL 30"]

output = []
for line in raw_data:
    if 'SATID' in line:  #making sure it is not an empty line
        timestamp = line.split(' SATID ')[0].split('Timestamp: ')[1].rstrip(' ')
        data = line.split(' SATID ')[1:]
        for record in data:
            if 'VAL1' in record:  #making sure it is not an empty record
                satid = record.split(' VAL1 ')[0]
                val1 = record.split(' VAL1 ')[1].split(' VAL2 ')[0]
                val2 = record.split(' VAL2 ')[1].split(' SIGNAL ')[0]
                signal = record.split(' SIGNAL ')[1].rstrip(' ')
                output.append({'Timestamp':timestamp,
                               'SATID':satid,
                               'VAL1':val1,
                               'VAL2':val2,
                               'SIGNAL':signal})


# output is now a list of dictionaries
for d in output:
    print(d)
```

Comment: Thanks Edwin... looks like an ingenous approach. One question, however: how can I do so that each column is preserved, and I can assign its contents to a particular variable, such as in the example shown originally? (see: time,sat1,sat2,sat3,sat4 above)

Comment: You can do whatever you want with the 'list of dictionaries', or you can modify when looping to do your own thing, this you can do instead of `output.append()`. Just remember, the first loop is line-by-line, to get the timestamp, the second loop is record-by-record in that line. This example was only to get you thinking, and only using standard functions, you really should look into pandas, which was mentioned in one of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since the column edges do not intersect, you can treat your file as fixed-width file and use function `read_fwf`. You will have to prepare column specifications list - a list of tuples that specify the first and the last position of each column. Here's the *beginning* of the specs (it is boring, but you have to do it only once):

```
specs = [(0,11),(11,20),(20,26),(26,29),(29,33),(33,37),
         (37,42),(42,45),(45,52),(52,55),(55,61),(61,63)]
pd.read_fwf('foo.txt',header=None,colspecs=specs)
#            0         1      2     3     4     5     6      7       8     9   \
#0  Timestamp:  00:47:14  SATID  13.0  VAL1  28.0  VAL2  227.0  SIGNAL  37.0   
#1  Timestamp:  00:48:14  SATID  13.0  VAL1  28.0  VAL2  227.0  SIGNAL  37.0   
#2  Timestamp:  00:49:14    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN   

#      10   11  
#0    NaN  NaN  
#1    NaN  NaN  
#2  SATID  1.0
```